# Tracking requests paths to servers behind a load balancer

Tags: rest, load-balancing, server-configuration

Suppose we have two servers A and B behind some load balancer that distributes requests between these servers somehow. What is the best practice of tracking which server processed a request? Suppose we have REST API with one endpoint `GET /ping`. Is it a good idea to include the host information into headers for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we do usually, is that we configure the LB to include a header only if the client requested it.
When you forge your /ping query, also add a header only known by you , like "X-Debug-Me: true". When this header is present, then either your LB or your server can insert its real hostname into whatever header you want.

Baptiste

Answer (score 0):

are you attempting to track this at the LB or at the origin/API servers?

shouldn't the host information already be in the header?  is the LB acting as a reverse-proxy and replacing the requesting hostname with it's own hostname?

i would agree with @baptiste that if you need to track this type of information a custom header is the best way to do it.